# Trying to average 10 numbers in VB.Net Can someone tell me why my code doesnt work?

Tags: vb.net

This code is supposed to collect 10 numbers in the form and calculate the average. When I pres the button for calculating nothing shows up. Why?
*edit I just started programing today so I don't know much

Public Class Form1

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Public Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10 As Integer
    Dim Calc As String
    Dim textbox11 As String
    Calc = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3 + TextBox4 + TextBox5 + TextBox6 + TextBox7 + TextBox8 + TextBox9 + TextBox10 / 10
    TextBox11 = Calc


End Sub

Public Sub TextBox11_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox11.TextChanged
    Dim TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10 As Integer
    Dim Calc As String
    Dim textbox11 As String
    Calc = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3 + TextBox4 + TextBox5 + TextBox6 + TextBox7 + TextBox8 + TextBox9 + TextBox10 / 10
    textbox11 = Calc

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to use the `Text` property for each textbox.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: If you have 10 TextBoxes named TextBoxX then do not declare 10 integer with the same names. It is really confusing

Comment: Dang. I didn't even see that the OP had done that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repetition, you can do this:

```
Calc = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5,
        TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10}.
        Select(Function(txt) Convert.ToDouble(txt.Text)).Average
```

Now this still a lot of repetition, so I'd suggest you group your textboxes under a common parent, such as a panel or a group box. Then instead of the above array use

```
pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
```

Using this approach, you can increase or decrease the amount of TextBoxes in designer - this code will auto-adjust and always give you proper answer.

Comment: @user3438398: My pleasure. Don't forget to accept one of the answers. When you earn enough reputation, you can also upvote any number of answers you find useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: @David Tansey has covered one, which is that you are trying to add the textbox controls together, not their values. The other is that you are only dividing the last value by ten.

You need to put all the values in brackets:

```
Calc = (TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text + TextBox4.Text + TextBox5.Text + TextBox6.Text + TextBox7.Text + TextBox8.Text + TextBox9.Text + TextBox10.Text) / 10
```

There is still a lot that can go wrong with this, e.g. if a value cannot be treated as a number, but that is a whole other conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare 10 integers with the same name of the TextBox present on your form.
Your code sums this integers insted of the TextBox values.
You could remove the declaration of the integers and use the value inside the textbox after converting them to an integer value

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Calc As Integer
    Calc = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox7.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox8.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox9.Text) + _
           Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text)) / 10
   TextBox11.Text = Calc.ToString
End Sub
```

Notice the parenthesis around the whole sum and the divide by 10 only on the result.
Of course this is just an example. There is also the problem of the correct validation of the input fields. If you type something that cannot be converted to an integer, this code will fail.

You could remedy this problem using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check if the values in the textboxes are really integer values.

Comment: While @Neolisk has a very clever solution -- I think Steve is explaining it in a way that is more helpful to a newcomer to programming.